# NodeJS deployment on Azure package problems

Tags: node.js, azure

When I deploy my NodeJS application on Azure, one is my Node packages gets broken. The error I get is:

```
Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

\\?\D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\bcrypt\lib\binding\bcrypt_lib.node
    at Error (native)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:597:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\bcrypt\bcrypt.js:6:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\models\user.model.js:3:14)
```

When I download my deployed files back, it doesn't even work locally anymore. I have to reinstall the bcrypt package locally again to get it working.

Does anyone knows why this happens?

UPDATE:
I've found a way to work around this. If I manually enter "npm install bcrypt" in my server it works... . Offcourse I can't do this after every deployment myself... .

UPDATE:
I've checked which version Azure installed before the fix and after the fix of the bcrypt package and it is the same version... . I don't why this is happening... .

package.json

```
{
  "name": "AzureRest",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node-pre-gyp": "~0.6.x",
    "bcrypt": "~1.0.2",
    "body-parser": "~1.16.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.0",
    "ejs": "~2.5.5",
    "express": "~4.14.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.3.0",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.1",
    "mocha": "^3.2.0",
    "mongoose": "~4.9.0",
    "mongoose-pagination": "~1.0.0",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "passport": "^0.3.2",
    "passport-jwt": "^2.2.1",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.2",
    "supertest": "^3.0.0",
    "validator": "^7.1.0",
    "slack-node": "^0.1.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: what is you local os and what is in azure?

Comment: My local os is Windows and I think that my API app also runs on Windows. The strange thing is, is that the person that deployed before me doesn't have this problem. And I can't ask him because he isn't here anymore.

Comment: One question does node_module is already inside your deployment code or you use npm install there .

Comment: I'm deploying my code without the node_module folder and the Azure deployment does automatically does "npm install".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have install all the essential component needed before using it.
The node package you are using is this i think
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

check out this link for different OS requirement before using this.

https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/wiki/Installation-Instructions

**and after that** 
make sure you run `npm install` in server, don't use the node_module folder as it is in the server.

If you have node_module in deployment code delete that and install by `npm install` again. It looks like that you are using node_module folder same in the server too .

Comment: When I deploy my code it gets deployed without the node_module folder. (It first goes to a bitbucket git -> Jenkins get triggered --> Jenkins downloads and pushen it to the Azure app. And Azure itself does the npm install again.

Comment: How does your package.json look like?

Comment: I will add this in the main post